# Using Max in group by

Tags: mysql, group-by, max

I have the following query and I want it to generate the result with just the latest date for the category for a store instead of giving out per date transaction:

```
SELECT c.store,d.node_name category, x.txn_dt, x.txn_tm time, count(c.txn_id) Buyer
FROM pos_swy.5_centerstore_triptype c
join pos_swy.3_txn_itm t on c.txn_id=t.txn_id
join pos_swy.1_upc_node_map d on t.upc_id=d.upc_id
join pos_swy.3_txn_hdr x on t.txn_id=x.txn_id
group by store,txn_dt,node_name;
```

I tried using max(x.txn_dt) but it really didn't solve the purpose.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get top n records for each group of grouped results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results)

Comment: you shouldn't group by field for which you are applying aggregate function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may need the order by ?

```
    SELECT c.store,d.node_name category, max(x.txn_dt) max_date, x.txn_tm time, count(c.txn_id) Buyer
    FROM pos_swy.5_centerstore_triptype c
    join pos_swy.3_txn_itm t on c.txn_id=t.txn_id
    join pos_swy.1_upc_node_map d on t.upc_id=d.upc_id
    join pos_swy.3_txn_hdr x on t.txn_id=x.txn_id
    group by node_name
    order by max_date desc 

         -- you can change limit 1 to what ever you want to get results
```

Comment: Hey but I need to get only the max/current date for each category and not not repeat the categories for per date. It just needs to display the most recent date only.

Comment: its difficult to understand like that can you provide fiddle example ?

Comment: so the query you gave me gives the result with the most recent date and goes to the last date. So data is generated for each day. But I want: c.store, d.node_name, max(x.txn_dt), time, count where x.txn_dt should be containing one value for each category and that value should be the most recent one

Comment: Well it still gives me all the dates in the descending order

Comment: yeah the only latest date that category was purchased

Comment: that returns only one row :(

Comment: you want every category , one max date ? then try this edited answer